# Worst test case for SPFA

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Recently, I have read about Shortest Path Faster Algorithm. I am wondering how to construct a test case for which standard implementation of SPFA wolud be very, very slow. Do you know any?

By standard implementation, I mean this one from Wikipedia:

```
 procedure Shortest-Path-Faster-Algorithm(G, s)
1    for each vertex v ≠ s in V(G)
2        d(v) := ∞
3    d(s) := 0
4    offer s into Q
5    while Q is not empty
6        u := poll Q
7        for each edge (u, v) in E(G)
8            if d(u) + w(u, v) < d(v) then
9                d(v) := d(u) + w(u, v)
10                if v is not in Q then
11                    offer v into Q
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the test case proposed on wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_Path_Faster_Algorithm#Worst-case_performance

Comment: I think I don't understand it. I've generated a graph with 10^5 vertices and 5 * 10^5 edges. There are 10^5 edges of form (i, i+1) with small weights (random weights between 1 and 80). And there are 4 * 10^5 random edges with weights from 6000 to 10000. But my program works very fast for this test case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example. There are N vertices. 1st vertex is the start and Nth vertex is the End. For ith vertex, there is 2 edges: (i, i+1, 1) and (1, i, 2*N) where (a,b,c) means there is an edge from a to b with weight c.

It is easy to see that the shortest path at this graph is 1->2->3->4->...->N. 
Assume that for the 7th line of your spfa algorithm :for each edge (u, v) in E(G), the vertex with bigger id get accessed before the vertex with smaller id. Then the ith vertex will be push into the queue max(1,i-1) times. So the total execution time is O(N^2).

Further more, if for the 7th line, the vertex with bigger id get accessed later than the vertex with smaller id, then the execution time is O(N).

For spfa, there will always exists a traverse order of the 7th line which leads to the worst time complexity, and always exists a traverse order of the 7th line which leads to the best time complexity. The critical thing is how the information is been spread through the shortest path.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Ke Yang's answer, the worst case for a graph with 5 Vertices would be: [image: Graph with 5 vertices]

In each iteration the queue would have the following elements (the head of the queue is the left most element):

```
[1]
[5, 4, 3, 2]
[4, 3, 2]
[3, 2]
[2]
[5, 4, 3]
[4, 3]
[3]
[5, 4]
[4]
[5]
```

This shows a pattern: 4 + 3 + 2 + 1, that would suggest that its O(N^2).

However looking more closely, every time a vertex is polled(dequed) all of it's outbound edges are considered, line 7. Thus the if in line 8 is executed:

| Vertex | Times dequed | Outbound edges | total execution of if |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 5 | 4 | 0 | 4 |

In total we would have:
Number of times the if is executed:

[image]

Which is O(V^3), where V is the number of vertices. Because this example graph would be dense, having O(V^2) edges. The final complexity could be written as O(V*E), where E is the number of edges. The same complexity as the worst case for SPFA. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_Path_Faster_Algorithm#Worst-case_performance

Answer (score 0):

I tried testing all of the previous answers with actual code, and none of them appear to be correct except for Luis's. (SPFA runs in $O(N)$ time on both Ke's and Vit's answers).

Note that Luis's construction produces a dense graph. For completeness, here's an additional test case I came up with that involves $O(N)$ edges with non-negative weights, where SPFA runs in $\Theta(N^2)$ time. The construction is as follows:

1. Set the source vertex to $0$
2. For $i\in [0,N/2)$, add edge $i\to N/2$ with weight $N-i$
3. For $i\in [0,N/2-1)$, add edge $i\to i+1$ with weight 0
4. For $i\in [N/2+1, N)$, add edge $N/2\to i$ with weight 0

Vertex $N/2$ gets pushed to the queue $\Theta(N)$ times, and every time we pop it from the queue it takes $\Theta(N)$ time to iterate over its adjacency list, yielding the desired complexity.

C++ source code:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, pair<int, int> p) {
    os << "{" << p.first << ", " << p.second << "}";
    return os;
}
template <class T> ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const vector<T> &v) {
    os << "{";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size(v); ++i) {
        if (i) os << ", ";
        os << v[i];
    }
    os << "}";
    return os;
}

struct Edge {
    int u, v, w;
};

vector<int> spfa(int N, vector<Edge> edges) {
    vector<vector<pair<int, int>>> adj(N);
    for (auto [u, v, w] : edges) {
        assert(0 <= u && u < N);
        assert(0 <= v && v < N);
        adj[u].push_back({v, w});
    }
    cerr << "Input:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        cerr << "adj[" << i << "] = ";
        cerr << adj[i] << "\n";
    }
    cerr << "\n";
    vector<int> d(N, INT_MAX);
    d[0] = 0;
    queue<int> q;
    vector<bool> in_queue(N);
    int ops = 0;
    cerr << "Ops:\n";
    auto offer = [&](int v) {
        if (in_queue.at(v)) return;
        cerr << "offer "
             << "v = " << v << " "
             << "d[v] = " << d[v] << "\n";
        // cerr << "offer " << v << " " << d << "\n";
        in_queue.at(v) = true;
        q.push(v);
    };
    auto poll = [&]() {
        int u = q.front();
        q.pop();
        assert(in_queue.at(u));
        in_queue.at(u) = false;
        return u;
    };
    offer(0);
    while (!q.empty()) {
        int u = poll();
        cerr << "poll "
             << "u = " << u << " "
             << "d[u] = " << d[u] << "\n";
        // cerr << "poll " << u << " " << d << "\n";
        for (auto [v, w] : adj[u]) {
            ++ops;
            int new_d = d[u] + w;
            if (new_d < d[v]) d[v] = new_d, offer(v);
        }
    }
    cerr << "ops = " << ops << "\n";
    return d;
}

// Ke Yang's case (0-indexed)
// ops ~ 3*N
vector<Edge> gen_ke(int N) {
    vector<Edge> edges;
    for (int i = N - 1; i > 0; --i) edges.push_back({0, i, 2 * N});
    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; ++i) edges.push_back({i, i + 1, 1});
    return edges;
}

// ops ~ 3*N
vector<Edge> gen_vit(int N) {
    vector<Edge> edges;
    for (int i = N - 1; i > 0; --i) edges.push_back({0, i, 3 * N - 2 * i});
    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; ++i) edges.push_back({i, i + 1, 1});
    return edges;
}

// O(N^2) edges, ops ~ N^3 / 6
vector<Edge> gen_luis(int N) {
    vector<Edge> edges;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for (int j = i + 2; j < N; ++j) edges.push_back({i, j, 2 * (N - i)});
    for (int i = 0; i + 1 < N; ++i) edges.push_back({i, i + 1, 1});
    return edges;
}

// O(N) edges, ops ~ N^2/4
vector<Edge> gen_good(int N) {
    vector<Edge> edges;
    for (int i = 0; i < N / 2; ++i) edges.push_back({i, N / 2, N - i});
    for (int i = N / 2 + 1; i < N; ++i) edges.push_back({N / 2, i, 0});
    for (int i = 0; i < N / 2 - 1; ++i) edges.push_back({i, i + 1, 0});
    return edges;
}

int main() {
    int N = 100;
    // auto edges = gen_ke(N);
    // auto edges = gen_vit(N);
    // auto edges = gen_luis(N);
    auto edges = gen_good(N);
    vector<int> dists = spfa(N, edges);
    cout << dists << "\n";
}
```

Output for Ke Yang's test case on $N=10$:

```
Input:
adj[0] = {{9, 20}, {8, 20}, {7, 20}, {6, 20}, {5, 20}, {4, 20}, {3, 20}, {2, 20}, {1, 20}, {1, 1}}
adj[1] = {{2, 1}}
adj[2] = {{3, 1}}
adj[3] = {{4, 1}}
adj[4] = {{5, 1}}
adj[5] = {{6, 1}}
adj[6] = {{7, 1}}
adj[7] = {{8, 1}}
adj[8] = {{9, 1}}
adj[9] = {}

Ops:
offer v = 0 d[v] = 0
poll u = 0 d[u] = 0
offer v = 9 d[v] = 20
offer v = 8 d[v] = 20
offer v = 7 d[v] = 20
offer v = 6 d[v] = 20
offer v = 5 d[v] = 20
offer v = 4 d[v] = 20
offer v = 3 d[v] = 20
offer v = 2 d[v] = 20
offer v = 1 d[v] = 20
poll u = 9 d[u] = 20
poll u = 8 d[u] = 20
poll u = 7 d[u] = 20
poll u = 6 d[u] = 20
poll u = 5 d[u] = 20
poll u = 4 d[u] = 20
poll u = 3 d[u] = 20
poll u = 2 d[u] = 20
poll u = 1 d[u] = 1
offer v = 2 d[v] = 2
poll u = 2 d[u] = 2
offer v = 3 d[v] = 3
poll u = 3 d[u] = 3
offer v = 4 d[v] = 4
poll u = 4 d[u] = 4
offer v = 5 d[v] = 5
poll u = 5 d[u] = 5
offer v = 6 d[v] = 6
poll u = 6 d[u] = 6
offer v = 7 d[v] = 7
poll u = 7 d[u] = 7
offer v = 8 d[v] = 8
poll u = 8 d[u] = 8
offer v = 9 d[v] = 9
poll u = 9 d[u] = 9
ops = 25
```

Answer (score -2):

Ke Yang's tests can be easy broken by random shuffle of edges.

Small modification brakes this trick: edges must be (i, i+1, 1) and (1, i, N*3-i*2).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33023155)

Comment: It is answer to the comment above. But by stupidity of local rules I can't answer to it.